# Toggle to display/hide menu, with flexbox and list items

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, navigation

**EDIT:** Thanks for answering! I've updated the codepen to reflect the final code, if anyone is interested. The code in the post is the original code that wasn't working.

---

I've been through probably 15 tutorials by now, but so far none of them are working.

**Here's the challenge:**

I've made a navbar for desktop, using an unordered list for the menu items, and organizing them with flexbox.

In the mobile version, I'd like the menu items to hide/appear by pressing a toggle. I've found that most tutorials does this by throwing a div around these items, but that would mess up the flexbox.

**tldr; How can I make a navbar, made up of list items in a flexbox, to appear/disappear by pressing a toggle?**

Here is my code:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/KaizerLBA/pen/QWNoWLa)

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><!--Logo in nav-->
            <a href="index.html">
            <div class="logo" id="pageTop">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Company logo">
            </div></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="projects.html">Prosjekter</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="consultants.html">Konsulenter</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="about.html">Om Sirius</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="blog.html">Blogg</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
 <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

header {
    background-color:#0f2530;
}

Nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Nav li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3.6vh;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: grid;
    align-items: end;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3vh 0;
}

.nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

li a:link, li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {   

  .nav {
    display: none;
  }  
  
nav ul {
    display: block;
}

nav li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
  
.nav-toggle {
  display: block;
}
```

I was imagining a JS solution, [like a slightly altered one of what W3 suggests here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp), but using class instead of ID to target all list items. However, that doesn't work:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementByClassName("nav");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I feel like there should be a simple solution, but I haven't found it yet. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You could just add a class to the `nav` element and show/hide it with js.

Comment: @pistevw Yeah, that's basically what I'd like to do! I'm not that experienced with writing my own JS, though. Do you know how could I do that in a simple way?

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to show/hide on toggle? Usually, if you want to show/hide content on small screens, you do that with css media queries.

Comment: @pistevw Yes, usually I'd use a media query. However, I wanted to use a toggle because the menu was taking up alot of the screen, so I wanted to hide it by default, but provide easy to access by a toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Semantic Elements and right approach to To create a show/hide navigation bar, that works on all devices.

Please target `<nav>` element instead of `<li>`

**Updated snippet :-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Mika's Portfolio</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium Web' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
header {
    background-color:#0f2530;
    min-height: 40px;
}
Nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
Nav li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3.6vh;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: grid;
    align-items: end;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3vh 0;
}
.nav-toggle {
    display: none;
}
li a:link, li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.bar {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 48px;
    top: 6px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    display:none
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
 #nav {
display:none;
}
.bar {
display:block;
}
 nav ul {
 display: block;
}
 nav li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
 .nav-toggle {
 display: block;
}
</style>
<body>
<header> <a href="index.html">
  <div class="logo" id="pageTop"> <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Company logo"> </div>
  </a> <a class="bar" href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav"><a href="projects.html">Prosjekter</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="consultants.html">Konsulenter</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="about.html">Om Sirius</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="blog.html">Blogg</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<script>


function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Priya, absolute lifesaver! I have updated the codepen, so that if anyone is interested can see the final code in action.